# What are the main points of the top-down vs bottom-up paradigm in neural networks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I've been reading some papers on human pose estimation and I'm starting to see the terms top-down and bottom-up crop up a lot. For example in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06937.pdf):

> Our hourglass module differs from these designs mainly
>   in its more symmetric distribution of capacity between bottom-up processing
>   (from high resolutions to low resolutions) and top-down processing (from low
>   resolutions to high resolutions)

Okay, so what are the main observations or distinctions of top-down vs bottom-up? Why does it make sense to have a paradigm in which we talk about these specifically?